# Cannot set property 'size' of undefined 4

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new of using node.js and I get these error :

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'size' of undefined
>       at Object. (C:\Users\User\Documents\latihannode.js\javascript4\test\script
>   4.js:4:10)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:576:3)

in the notification this is the error code:

```
die.size = 10;
```

this is the code in page script4.js:

```
var dice = require('./dice');
var die = dice.die;

    die.size = 10;
    console.log(die.roll());
    console.log(die.roll());
    console.log(die.roll());
    console.log(die.totalRolls);

    console.log(die);
```

and this is in page dice.js:

```
var die = {
  size: 6,
  totalRolls: 0,
  roll: function() {
    var result = Math.ceil(this.size * Math.random());
    this.totalRolls += 1;
    return result;
  }
};


exports.game = die;
exports.name = "My dice exports";
```

Comment: Have you checked if `dice` is null or not?

Comment: The problem is that `die` is undefined, just as it says in the error message. Does `dice` have a `die` export?

Comment: Your naming seems to be contradictory: you're trying to access something you don't export-might want to get that figured out before going much further.

Comment: i already give export die in dice.js but i think is in require @torazaburo

Comment: So many dice problems today. Guess a new semester started and everyone from the class is asking questions. The error is clearly stating that `dice.die;` is undefined. Look at your exports, do you see die? No. I see game and name. Basic debugging `var dice = require('./dice'); console.log(dice);` <-- look to see what dice outputs to your developer console.

Comment: @epascarello Just die already. See what I did there?

Comment: @DaveNewton You just broke the new rules. I should report you for not being nice. lol

Comment: @epascarello the output is { game: 6, name: 'My dice exports' } so what should I do.

Comment: And you see, there is no die in there. For some reason you defined the export of die as game....

Comment: can you give me some idea what should I change @epascarello

Comment: I did... did you read the last comment?

Comment: oh, ok i just see it , thank you @epascarello

Answer (score 2):

Change here :

```
var dice = require('./dice');
var die = dice.game; // not die.die
```